# Truncating table table optimal solution

Tags: java, oracle, performance, plsql, spring-integration

I have created a spring integration workflow that loads a data from csv to oracle database. This is a cluster environment where every node process one csv file and load the data in temp table.

Structure of temp table: (index on `AccountNumber`)

```
ID
AccountNumber
ItemId
Value
```

I have a spring integration rabbitmq configuration which publish filenames to the queue. Each node in a cluster pick up only one file, read the csv from file system(Shared file system and oracle database) and load the data in TEMP table. (The size of each csv is 2GB).

After loading all the data in temp table one node is supposed to move the data from temp table to main table which has a same structure as temp table.

Main table: (index on `Account Number`)

```
Id
AccountNumber
ItemId
Value
```

I have created a stored procedure which delete the existing account numbers from main table and load accounts in main table.

Once data has been moved to main table, I am deleting data from temp table at the end of the procedure.

My question is what would be the optimal way to truncate this table.

Problem: suppose i have this record in my main table.

Main table:

```sql
Account Number   ItemId   ItemValue
-----------------------------------
123456             5        XYZ
123456             6        ABC
123456             7        DEF
```

Now I get this entry from csv to temp table:

```sql
AccountNumber    ItemId    ItemValue
------------------------------------
123456             5        FGH
```

now my main table should have only one value. Rows with ItemId 6 and 7 should be removed.

```sql
Account Number   ItemId    ItemValue
-------------------------------------
123456             5        FGH
```

Can I achieve this with merge into?

**Scenario 1**:

Would it be better to truncate this table before loading the data in a TEMP table? (Two separate database transaction one for truncate table and another for data movement).

(This calls before publishing the filenames in a queue)
one procedure to cleanup the temp table in batches before loading.

Step 1:

```sql
create or replace procedure CleanTempTable
IS
v_numberRows int :=20000;

BEGIN
loop
Delete from TEMP where rownum <= v_numberRows;
EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

One procedure to move the data from temp to main.

This calls at the end in consolidation stage.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA_TO_CONSOLIDATE (updatecount OUT NUMBER )
IS
  cnt number := 0;
  account_num MAIN_TABLE.ACCOUNT_NO%TYPE;
  CURSOR account_cursor IS
    SELECT distinct ACCOUNT_NO from TEMP_TABLE;
BEGIN
OPEN account_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH account_cursor INTO account_num;
        EXIT WHEN account_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        delete from MAIN where ACCOUNT_NO = account_num;
    insert into MAIN(ID,ACCOUNT_NO,FACT_ID,FACT_VALUE) select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval,temp.ACCOUNT_NO,temp.VALUE from TEMP temp
    where ACCOUNT_NO = account_num;
        cnt := cnt + sql%rowcount;
    commit;
    END LOOP;
    updatecount := cnt;
    CLOSE account_cursor;
END LOAD_DATA_TO_CONSOLIDATE;
```

Scenario 2:

would it be better to truncate this table after moving the data from TEMP table to main table.(Everything within one stored procedure (in one DB transaction))

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA_TO_CONSOLIDATE (updatecount OUT NUMBER )
IS
  cnt number := 0;
  account_num MAIN_TABLE.ACCOUNT_NO%TYPE;
  CURSOR account_cursor IS
    SELECT distinct ACCOUNT_NO from TEMP_TABLE;
BEGIN
OPEN account_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH account_cursor INTO account_num;
        EXIT WHEN account_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        delete from MAIN where ACCOUNT_NO = account_num;
    insert into MAIN(ID,ACCOUNT_NO,FACT_ID,FACT_VALUE) select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval,temp.ACCOUNT_NO,temp.VALUE from TEMP temp
    where ACCOUNT_NO = account_num;
        cnt := cnt + sql%rowcount;
    commit;
    END LOOP;
    updatecount := cnt;
    CLOSE account_cursor;
delete from TEMP; //removing all data
END LOAD_DATA_TO_CONSOLIDATE;
```

Comment: Why are you using a temp table ?

Comment: And since you're using spring integration, read file line by line (since they are 2gb files) and send each line for processing. You can have multiple consumers on your queue getting the files.

Comment: Yes i have a configuration of rabbitmq listener on each node which receives a one csv file each -> parse it -> Load the data in Temp table.

csv 1 -> 1 node -> parse it -> TEMP Table
csv 2 -> 2 Node -> parse it -> TEMP Table

At the end
Any One Node -> Consolidate data from TEMP To MAIN Table using store proc mentioned in question.

Comment: instead of sending lines I am sending a filename..which further read the csv from filesystem. Do you mean i should process the csv lines in batches and rabbitmq consumers should read the lines instead of file?

Comment: Yes I mean you can have your consumer just read the file line by line and the send the next channel for transforming line into value object, then if you need to do some processing to another channel, otherwise just pass the value object to the DAL that persists it. I just fail to understand why you use a temp table ? Why not directly saving the the main table ?

Comment: i understand with this approach i don't need temp table any more. However, i don't know how to determine the size of each fragment having a records from csv? means what would the size of messagePayload? 500 records? 1000 records? How to determine maximum size that might put a strain on network?

Comment: Where are the files located? In a directory on the database server?

Comment: Size doesn’t have an influence, you’re just reading the CSV line by line, transform each line to a value object for your service layer, that would pass it to your DAL who would persist it. Either that or I’m missing a point in your processing on why size matters.

Comment: Incidentally you shouldn't use the term *truncating*. It's confusing, as TRUNCATE is a SQL command, and it does something different from what you're talking about.

Comment: Files are located on a directory..Ex. /app/config/Sample_1.csv /app/config/Sample_2.csv  /app/config/Sample_3.csv

Comment: I read these csv from filesystem. perform some parsing and validation and put the data in temp table using spring jdbc template.

Comment: It’s pretty classic flow, I suggest not using temp tables.

Comment: *"Files are located on a directory"* Yes but is that directory in a filesystem on the database server? Or the server where you run the spring application? Or a third place?

Comment: @APC does it matter ?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk - if the object of the exercise is to optimize the exercise then surely we ought to include network i/o in our considerations?

Comment: @APC All right, He said he’s using Spring Integratuon, so I was just thinking he’d be using an InboundChannelAdapter that will get him the file from wherever, the cost of that being out of optimization actually in case of Spring Integration use.

Answer (score 0):

From my, Oracle-ish point of view, neither of the options you suggested. Here's why:

- you're *doubling* the job by first loading data into a temporary table, and then copying it into the main table
- row-by-row processing is slow-by-slow
- committing withing the loop might lead to ORA-01555 error
- deleting (`DELETE` command) is always slower than truncating (`TRUNCATE`)

A suggestion: in order to avoid the temporary table, use **external tables** feature which uses your CSV file as if it was an ordinary Oracle table.

It means that everything could have been done in just two statements:

```
-- Delete rows from the MAIN table whose ACCOUNT_NO exists in the CSV file
delete from main m
where exists (select null 
              from external_table t
              where t.account_no = m.account_no
             );

-- Insert rows into the MAIN table
insert into main (col1, col2, ...)
select col1, col2 from external_table;
```

---

Alternatively - which would probably perform the best - you could `UPDATE` values for `ACCOUNT_NO` that already exists in the table and `INSERT` only rows that don't; instead of two commands, use a single, fast `MERGE` statement (also known as *upsert*)

```
merge into main m
  using (select t.account_no, t.col1, t.col2, ...
         from external_table t
        ) x
on m.account_no = x.account_no
when matched then update set m.col1 = x.col1,
                             m.col2 = x.col2, ...
when not matched then insert (account_no, col1, col2, ...)
                      values (x.account_no, x.col1, x.col2, ...);
```

With `MERGE`, you don't load here, delete from there, insert from here to there ... pretty neat and, as I said, fast. No need for PL/SQL at all.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
The reason why i am not using the mergeinto statement is I want to delete All the entries from main table for account numbers exist in temp table. mergeinto statement will only update the existing entry in main table and insert otherwise. But it will not delete the existing rows in main table.

Comment: True, but that's what you are doing anyway. First you want to delete ACCOUNT_NO rows from the MAIN table, and then insert the same ACCOUNT_NO values from the TEMP table. The result is that you have new values for those ACCOUNT_NO rows. MERGE does that in one pass.

Comment: My situation is slightly differ here.

suppose i have this record in my main table.

Main Table:
```
Account Number   ItemId   ItemValue
123456             5        XYZ
123456             6        ABC
123456             7        DEF
```
suppose i receive below entry in my temp table.
```
AccountNumber    ItemId    ItemValue
123456             5        FGH
```
now my main table should have only one value. rows with
 ItemId 6 and 7 should be removed.

Account Number   ItemId    ItemValue
123456             5        FGH

can i achieve this with merge into?

Comment: Updated the problem statement in question as well.

Comment: MERGE can't delete any rows, so - no, that wouldn't be possible. DELETE + MERGE would.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For performance reason can i limit DELETE + MERGE queries using rownum in order to perform these operations in batches because there will be huge data on both the tables.

Comment: I can't tell. Try it and see which option behaves the best.

Comment: Merge can delete rows. It's an option for the `WHEN MATCHED` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @eaolson. Documentation says: "The only rows affected by this clause are those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge operation." What I meant to say was that - at least, the way I understood it - MERGE itself can't remove rows that aren't affected by the UPDATE. From the example the OP posted, certain ITEMIDs would be updated, but rows whose ITEMIDs don't exist in the CSV wouldn't be affected (i.e. deleted), while they should. Sorry for not explaining better what I meant to say.